# Errors C2144 & C4430 When Building Win32 DLL

Tags: c++

I'm not a C++ programmer, but I'm trying to build a simple Win32 DLL. However, with the below code I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-      int
```

DemoLib.h

```
#pragma once
#define DLL_EXP extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DLL_EXP void Foo(char* data_in, char *data_out);
```

DemoLib.cpp

```
#include "DemoLib.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
DLL_EXP void Foo(char* data_in, char *data_out)
{
    *data_out = *data_in  ; 
}
```

Exports.def

```
LIBRARY DemoLib
EXPORTS
   Foo   @1
```

Comment: Maybe the void needs to come before the void __declspec(dllexport) like this: `extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) Foo(char* data_in, char *data_out);`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah  Works either way round in my VS-2019. Maybe switch the order of your `#include` lines?

Comment: `stdafx.h` must be the first include, assuming you are using it as your precompiled header.

Comment: @AdrianMole it was just a guess.  I think the other comment about stdafx.h is definitely the right answer.  I don't know how I didn't notice that...

Comment: So Simple! Yes - stdafx.h must be the first include.